# How can I find out which mounted filesystems a running process sees?

Tags: linux, mount, process

After having a long debug session and finally finding out that in Fedora (and CentOS) php-fpm has its own mounted `/tmp` filesystem, which was caused by a systemd setting, `PrivateTmp`, I am wondering if there is a simple command to show which mounted filesystems a running process sees?

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, you can get this information from

```
/proc/<pid>/mounts
```

where `<pid>` is the ID of the process you are interested in. There is also:

```
/proc/<pid>/mountinfo
```

which contains additional information but it is in a different, non-`/etc/mtab`-compatible format.

Comment: thanks for your anwer. Found the "real" information under  /proc/<pid>/mountinfo.  Would have saved me hours. By the way its not in /proc/<pid>/mounts (you cannot see there the "real path")